# Select adjacent couples (or triads, etc ) from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I can do it by making use of the list indexes ...

```
lst =[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[ [lst[i] , lst[i+1]] for i in range( len(lst) - 1 )]
```

or:

```
lst =[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in range(len(lst)-1): 
    entities.append([lst[i],lst[i+1]])
```

But is there a smarter way? Maybe using iterators? What about performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You received some clever answers here, but I'd like to suggest that the most obvious way to do this just uses built-in slice indexing.  Like so:

```
def gen_k_slices(seq, k):
    for i in range(len(seq) - k + 1):
        yield seq[i:i+k]
```

Here's a little test driver:

```
TEST = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for k in range(8):
    print("k={} -> {}".format(k, list(gen_k_slices(TEST, k))))
```

and its output:

```
k=0 -> [[], [], [], [], [], [], []]
k=1 -> [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
k=2 -> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
k=3 -> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
k=4 -> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
k=5 -> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
k=6 -> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
k=7 -> []
```

I don't like the result for k=0 either ;-)

Answer (score 5):

For a general solution (since you asked for couples, triples, etc.), use [`itertools.tee`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

```
from itertools import tee

def adjacent_tuples(iterable, n=2):
    iterators = tee(iterable, n)
    for i, iterator in enumerate(iterators):
        for j in range(i):
            next(iterator)
    return zip(*iterators)
```

This uses a minimum of memory and works for any length of tuples:

```
>>> list(adjacent_tuples(range(8), 4))
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6, 7)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip()`:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

>>> list(zip(lst[:-1],lst[1:]))
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]

>>> list(zip(lst[:-2],lst[1:-1],lst[2:]))
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: You can write `zip(lst, lst[1:])` instead of `zip(lst[:-1],lst[1:])` because `zip` terminates on the shortest sequence. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can zip iterators, one regular and another one shifted:

```
>>> it = iter(lst)
>>> it.next()
1
>>> zip(iter(lst), it)
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
```

Here's an appropriate generator (using [izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)):

```
from itertools import izip


def my_zip(l):
    i1 = iter(l)
    i2 = iter(l)
    i2.next()
    for value in izip(i1, i2):
        yield value


lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print list(my_zip(lst))  # prints [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

An iterator would be like this.

```
def iterate_couples(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1): 
        yield [lst[i], lst[i + 1]]
```